# How to use saveAsTextFile on AWS?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark

I hope to get something by println, but by using AWS, it may not work, How can I save the content of println as a file on AWS using "saveAsTextFile"?
The original content of println is as following:

```
println("\n[ First output is ]")
output1.foreach(a => println("(" + a +"," + titles(a - 1) + ")"));
println("\n[ Second output us ]")
output2.foreach(a => println("(" + a +"," + titles(a - 1) + ")"));
```

output1 and output2 are both list made up of numbers. titles is also a list.
Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. By 'using AWS', do you mean you're running code on an EC2 instance and you want to save to the instance storage? Or saving something to S3 storage?

Comment: I see nothing specific about AWS in your question.

Comment: if on local machine, I can save print out content to a file by using > output.txt in command line, but run on AWS EC2, is it still worked? I just hope to save the print content to a file if run on AWS EC2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if both are `List`s, you may convert them into `RDD`s, using `SparkContext`'s  method `parallelize`.

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List("[ First output is ]") ++ output1.map(a => "(" + a + "," + titles(a - 1) + ")"))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(List("[ Second output is ]") ++ output2.map(a => "(" + a + "," + titles(a - 1) + ")"))
```

After this you can use `saveAsTextFile`, in your desired **s3** path.

```
rdd1.saveAsTextFile("s3://yourAccessKey:yourSecretKey@/out1.txt")
rdd2.saveAsTextFile("s3://yourAccessKey:yourSecretKey@/out2.txt")
```

I recommend you to read this blog, it might help you do understand important things about **S3** and `Apache-Spark` [Writing s3 data with Apache Spark](http://www.sparktutorials.net/reading-and-writing-s3-data-with-apache-spark)

Comment: Can I write "println("\n[ First output is ]")" in the example into the file? Thanks.

Comment: Let me explain myself, you are converting each line into one RDD entry, therefore you could add that line appending it to the list. The thing is that RDDs *tend* to be consistent, which means they have the same structure in all entries.

Comment: I see you save them separately, but do you know how to add a string like the content of println("\n[ First output is ]") to a file?

Comment: I told you, the string is just considered another entry of the RDD. However I added that line to the RDD.